# How can I replace characters in a string using a pointer? (in c code)

Tags: c, pointers, reference

How can I replace characters in a string using a pointer?  (in c code)

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = "Hello world!\n";
main()
{

        printf("String Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));
        printf("Original String: %s\n", code);

        char &code[7] = "W";    
        char &code[8] = "a";
        char &code[9] = "l";
        char &code[10] = "e";
        char &code[11] = "s";

        printf("New String: %s\n", code);

}
```

Comment: To start with, you *do* know that array indexes in C starts at zero? So the index of the `'W'` in `"Hello World"` is 6. Although you would notice that very quickly with this program after fixing the syntax.

Comment: Also, arrays and pointers are very often interchangeable, and you can use array indexing syntax to access elements when using pointer, as well as using an array as a pointer.

Comment: `memcpy(&code[6], "Wales", 5);`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a zero-based array index:

```
   code[6] = 'W';    
   code[7] = 'a';
   code[8] = 'l';
   code[9] = 'e';
   code[10] = 's';
```

Character literals are specified with single quotes rather than double.

The array variable is a synonym for the address of the first element. If you specifically want to use pointer syntax, you can replace `code[i]` with `*(code + i)`. For example:

```
   *(code + 6) = 'W';    
   *(code + 7) = 'a';
   *(code + 8) = 'l';
   *(code + 9) = 'e';
   *(code + 10) = 's';
```